# How to align xarray DataArray with length-1 dimension with a larger array?

Tags: python-xarray

I'd like to take an xarray dataset with a time dimension of 1, and simply replicate the data to increase the time dimension from 1 to N. What is the most efficient way to do this? I've tried several methods like expand_dims and stack but none of these seem to do what I want.

Ultimately I want to be able to do
moc10_H11 - moc_ctrl_clim
Where the result would have the same dimensions as moc10_H11 (35). Right now when I do this the time dimension of the output is only 1.

For clarity, moc_ctrl_clim :

```
Dimensions:
time: 1, lat_aux_grid: 395, moc_z: 61
Coordinates: time (time) object 0001-01-01 00:00:00
lat_aux_grid (lat_aux_grid) float32 -79.49 -78.95 -78.42 ... 89.47 90.0
moc_z (moc_z) float32 0.0 1e+03 ... 5.25e+05 5.5e+05
Data variables:
MOC (time, moc_z, lat_aux_grid) float64
dask.array<chunksize=(1, 61, 395), meta=np.ndarray>
```

and moc10_H11 has:

```
Dimensions:

time: 35, lat_aux_grid: 395, moc_z: 61
Coordinates: time (time) object 0001-01-01 00:00:00
lat_aux_grid (lat_aux_grid) float32 -79.49 -78.95 -78.42 ... 89.47 90.0
moc_z (moc_z) float32 0.0 1e+03 ... 5.25e+05 5.5e+05
Data variables:
MOC (time, moc_z, lat_aux_grid) float64
dask.array<chunksize=(1, 61, 395), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Comment: what would you like the new time dim to be indexed by? e.g. `pd.date_range(...)`? `range(10)`? and do you want the *time* values to be identical, or just the data?

Comment: I'm actually trying to subtract the mean field of a variable (which has 1 time entry), from another field with more than 1 time entry. 
It has : 
```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions:
time: 35, lat_aux_grid: 395, moc_z: 61
Coordinates:
time
(time)
object
0001-01-01 00:00:00 ... 1701-01-...
lat_aux_grid
(lat_aux_grid)
float32
-79.49 -78.95 -78.42 ... 89.47 90.0
moc_z
(moc_z)
float32
0.0 1e+03 ... 5.25e+05 5.5e+05
```
I thought replicating the mean field to match the same number of time dimensions would be the best way, but maybe thats not true...

Comment: Also, I want the data to be identical, not the time.

Comment: I answered based on how you describe the underlying problem in the comments. can you add this context to your question to make it clear why you're hoping to replicate the data?

Comment: The original post has been edited to clarify what I ultimately want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, squeeze the data so xarray's automatic alignment rules kick in:

```py
da = da.squeeze(dim='time', drop=True)
```

now, you can pair with an array indexed by time and the data will be broadcast automatically.

## Explanation

The reasoning behind this lies in the difference between [numpy's broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which is based on shape, and [xarray's broadcasting by dimension name](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name).

#### Numpy broadcasting by shape

From the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions and works its way left.
> Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

As an example, you can perform element-wise addition between a column vector and an array if the first dimensions align:

```py
In [3]: col_vector = np.ones(shape=(3, 1))

In [4]: col_vector
Out[4]:
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])

In [5]: array = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

In [6]: array
Out[6]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [7]: col_vector + array
Out[7]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.]])
```

when `col_vector` is added to `array`, numpy recognizes that `col_vector` has length 1 along axis 1, and `array` has length 4, so `col_vector` should be broadcast (tiled) along axis 1 to have length 4 before being added.

#### xarray broadcasting by dimension name

From the [xarray docs on computation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name):

> `DataArray` objects automatically align themselves (“broadcasting” in the numpy parlance) by dimension name instead of axis order. With xarray, you do not need to transpose arrays or insert dimensions of length 1 to get array operations to work, as commonly done in numpy with [`numpy.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) or [`numpy.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis).

Adding to this, in the [xarray docs on automatic alignment](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment):

> Xarray enforces alignment between *index* [Coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates) (that is, coordinates with the same name as a dimension, marked by *) on objects used in binary operations.
> [...]
> If coordinate values for a dimension are missing on either argument, all matching dimensions must have the same size.

Adapting the example above not only requires assigning names and coordinate dimensions, *but also dropping the second dimension from the column vector*:

```py
In [2]: vector = xr.DataArray(np.ones(shape=3), dims=['x'], coords=[[0, 1, 2]])

In [3]: vector
Out[3]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3)>
array([1., 1., 1.])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2

In [4]: arr = xr.DataArray(
   ...:     np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),
   ...:     dims=['x', 'time'],
   ...:     coords=[[0, 1, 2], pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')],
   ...: )

In [5]: arr
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, time: 4)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-04

In [6]: vector + arr
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, time: 4)>
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-04
```

#### broadcasting length-1 dimensions to longer dimensions

In your question, you have an array with length 1 along the time dimension which you'd like to broadcast against another array with a longer time coordinate. This is equivalent in the examples above to having a "vector" with length 1 in the time dimension:

```py
In [7]: vector = xr.DataArray(
   ...:     np.ones(shape=(3, 1)),
   ...:     dims=['x', 'time'],
   ...:     coords=[[0, 1, 2], pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=1, freq='D')],
   ...: )
```

When broadcasting this against `arr`, which has a time dimension with length 4, only the intersection is preserved:

```py
In [8]: vector + arr
Out[8]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, time: 1)>
array([[1.],
       [5.],
       [9.]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
```

The data can be broadcast against time by first compressing and dropping the time dim with [`da.squeeze`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.squeeze.html):

```py
In [9]: vector.squeeze('time', drop=True)  + arr
Out[9]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, time: 4)>
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-04
```

Note that this approach is ignoring the information in your first array in the `time` coordinate, instead assuming the information is applicable to all elements of `time` in the second array. If this is what you're looking for, then squeezing & dropping as shown here is the way to go.

Comment: Oh this works,  Many thanks for the thorough explanation.